# Cause of flv corruption in AIR output?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flv, corruption

I have a fairly complex AIR project which is compiling a lot of movieclips together using timelinemax and finally outputting the whole thing as an .flv using https://github.com/zeropointnine/leelib/tree/master/src/leelib/util/flvEncoder

I am getting corruption of the flv when certain videos are added to the timeline (all videos are embedded in movieclips in an external .swc).  Here's what the corruption looks like:
[image: corruption]

It looks as if the second video I add is being somehow combined with the first and going all crazy.  But the two movieclips containing these videos are never on the stage at the same time, they are added one by one when their part of the main timeline is reached, and removed afterwards.  This works in all other cases, and the corruption does not happen with certain videos.  I am creating all the flvs for embedding myself, in After Effects, and exporting them all with identical settings.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be causing this?  Sorry not to post any code, but there is just so much, I wouldn't know where to start, and I feel like this probably isn't a code problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't say for sure, but these artifacts show up when an PFrame or BFrame is overlayed over wront IFrame (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types)

Comment: Interesting. Are you able to say any more regarding how frames might get overlayed in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer seems to be: don't load in video files from an external .swc.  I moved all the movieclips containing video into my main .flv and the corruption is gone.  I don't understand it, but I'll take it.